# How to create own JUnit tests for own created Java Classes on JGraphT?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, junit, jgrapht

I'm using JGraphT framework working with graph models on Netbeans IDE. I have written some classes and try to write JUnit tests. But I can run tests at all. There are now option to run class file. Also this framework using maven and then I click Test file on testing class i get **this error:**

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-cli) on project jgrapht-demo: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

I think what this problems appear from pom.xml file and dependencies settings.

**This is my TestClass for MainWindow class which is empty and generated from MainWindows Class.** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXbin.png)

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXYrJ.png)

//---------------------------------

Comment: Show your directory structure and pom.xml

Comment: My pom.xml file http://pastebin.com/1STbwb2D

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1STbwb2D

Comment: Same situation appear then I download Jgrapt source project and create empty test JGraphAdapterDemo.java class .

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-cli) on project jgrapht-demo: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Answer (score 0):

The Surefire plugin fails because it finds no test. Add an empty test and it will not fail anymore.

Comment: I create empty test from souce class, this code is generated http://pastebin.com/D11SqidE

Comment: yes. maybe something wrong that i am using netbeans ide instead eclipse.  ?

Comment: Could you please add your directory layout to the question.

Comment: there defualt layout screen then you build jgrapht default source. It;s the same problem then you try to create junit tests for exmaple class

Comment: Could you please post a picture with the files tab

Comment: Could some try to open project from JGraphT lib and try to create JUnit test for example class from demo model ?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Could you publish the whole project on GitHub. This would be helpful for finding the problem.

Comment: I don't use github. Could you simple download jgrapht project zip file from jgrapht. Open project from netbeans and select on source file. Then biuld with dependencies and in demo module try to run main class. If is ok. Lib is already prepared to use. Then try to create simple test for one of example classes and try to run test? I am not able to do.

Comment: The problem still exists

Comment: Problem solved. I have created new project and imported JGrapht modules from lib folder like jar libraries and escaped from maven using.